# Java MySQL Delete duplicates Query on a date field

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to delete few entries from DB table based on a date filed.

For example, consider the following data.

```
 - Program Name -------    Job_Run_date 
 - program.exe  -------    2015-08-04     
 - program.exe  -------    2015-08-04    
 - program.exe  -------    2015-08-05      
 - program.exe  -------    2015-08-05      
 - program.exe  -------    2015-08-06
```

in the above list, the entry for 2015-08-04 occurred twice. The expected number of entries for each date field are only one per date. 
I would be storing each and every run information in a DB table, however I wouldn't be needing multiple entries for a program. But an entry is required to identify the processes, which have run on a particular date.

I have tried to run the following kind of queries from a java program, but some how the logic doesn't seem to work.
DELETE FROM PROCESS_DATA WHERE RUN_Date NOT IN ( SELECT RUN_Date FROM ( SELECT MIN(RUN_Date)  FROM PROCESS_DATA GROUP BY RUN_Date))

Any modifications to the query is taking a lot of time to run and couldn't find much info with respect to this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to fix this problem,

```
1. Before insertion, you can validate if there exists any record for this date.
2. Execute the below query
DELETE FROM PROCESS_DATA WHERE RUN_Date NOT IN ( SELECT distinct RUN_Date FROM PROCESS_DATA )
```

Comment: The provided logic doesnt work. If the dates are inserted in "YYYY MM DD" format, all different entries for the same date do not match. SO, the query doesnt work.